# How to set a little arrow next to icon in toolbar?

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I want something like this: [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) . A little arrow and icon but in a toolbar.

**EDIT:**

[image]

I have tried this:

```html
    mToolbar = (CustomToolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_ab_back_holo_light);
    mToolbar.setTitle(mMatchName);
    mToolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_options);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_right);
        }
    });
```

But this makes a big distance between arrow icon and Logo.

[image]

**Question:**

How do I put an arrow and a logo next to each other?

Comment: you already linked a tutorial to make it!! Just follow the steps and tell us if any problem occurs in the way.....

Comment: That tutorial is pretty much as simple as it gets. If you give us specifics we can help.

Comment: I have given specifics. Look at edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments I've found how to achieve in a toolbar the Up Navigation like this one:

[image]

We can create a custom layout and put it in a toolbar.

1) in onCreate method:

```html
        mToolbar = (CustomToolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setUpCustomUpNavigation();

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        // to disable title in a toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

2) setUpCustomUpNavigation() method.

```html
private void setUpCustomUpNavigation() {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View customUpNavView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.up_navigation_layout, null);

        // "ic_ab_back_holo_light.png" Located in ...android-sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\drawable-xhdpi
        ImageView backArrowImageView = (ImageView) customUpNavView.findViewById(R.id.backArrowImageView);

        ImageView logoToolbarImageView = (ImageView) customUpNavView.findViewById(R.id.logoToolbarImageView);

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) customUpNavView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);


        // set logo
        logoToolbarImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.help_toolbar_ic_selector);

        // set title
        titleTextView.setText(R.string.title_activity_help);

        mToolbar.addView(customUpNavView);
    }
```

3) toolbar.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<net.stargorod.dating.toolbar.CustomToolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
    style="@style/MyToolbar" />
```

4) in style.xml create the style: MyToolbar.

```html
    <!-- Toolbar style -->
    <style name="MyToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

**Result:**

[image]

That's it!

P.S. I'm sorry for my grammar mistakes.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.

Answer (score 1):

Your link takes you to an example of the old ActionBar, but you seem to be using the new toolbar.  The new toolbar design doesn't have icons like the old version, only text, so the extra space is by design.  If you want to use something like you linked then you need to use the ActionBar not a toolbar.

Here is a link on the new toolbar:
https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

vs. the old ActionBar
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html

Comment: Thanks, for answer! I think I need only to add custom layout to the toolbar, to achieve look of the old version.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to go full custom, but if you are going for the old school actionbar look, you might as well just use it :)

Comment: Well, I can't use action bar in my case. I need toolbar.